# How to sign a message with Gnosis safe?

Tags: solidity, signature, gnosis-safe, multisignature, gnosis

I need to sign the message to claim tokens in **[claim.hydradx.io](https://claim.hydradx.io/)** and I am trying to have a text of my message following the intruction below:

> If you have entered your ETH address manually, you will need to sign the message through the external wallet that holds the private keys of your xHDX tokens. Once you have signed the message, copy the signature (**starting with 0x**) to the respective field in the HydraDX Claim app.*

Where to signing messages in Gnosis or add a module to enable that functionality?

Comment: Let me know if it works for you or if not to delete it! ;) @BR Capital

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is provided via the [**CompatibilityFallbackHandler**](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/handler/CompatibilityFallbackHandler.sol). In your case, this could be enabled by default on all Safes created via the **Gnosis Safe** web interface.

Currently for signatures:

> Approve the message on-chain via the [SignMessage](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#VoidSigner). In this flow a Safe transaction is triggered. This is supported via the [WalletConnect SafeApp](https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4356253-walletconnect-safe-app).

> Collect signatures of the owners to create a composite signature that can be verified against the Safe owners and threshold. This would not require any on chain transaction, but is currently not supported by the web interface.